# How to get the name of color while having its RGB value in C#?

Tags: c#

I am creating an application to find the most used color of an image, i am up to getting the RGB value of the color, but how to get the color name, help plz.

Comment: May be this helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365935/trying-to-convert-rgb-from-a-net-color-to-a-string-such-as-red-or-blue

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where are you stuck? What do you expect to happen when the color is not one of the known named ones?

Answer (score 24):

As noted in comments, the [`KnownColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor) enumeration can be used to make this simpler:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Color color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(color.Name); // ffff0000

        var colorLookup = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))
               .Cast<KnownColor>()
               .Select(Color.FromKnownColor)
               .ToLookup(c => c.ToArgb());

        // There are some colours with multiple entries...
        foreach (var namedColor in colorLookup[color.ToArgb()])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(namedColor.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Original answer**

`Color.FromArgb` will give you a `Color`, but it will never have a name. You need to use reflection to get the named colours, as far as I'm aware.

Here's another version of Cole Campbell's solution which I was working up at the same time...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Color color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(color.Name); // ffff0000

        var colorLookup = typeof(Color)
               .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
               .Select(f => (Color) f.GetValue(null, null))
               .Where(c => c.IsNamedColor)
               .ToLookup(c => c.ToArgb());

        // There are some colours with multiple entries...
        foreach (var namedColor in colorLookup[color.ToArgb()])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(namedColor.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the [KnownColor enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) to avoid refelection.

Comment: `KnownColor` is not really helpful in this case, because is also contains system colors like `ActiveCaptionText`. Therefore this method will also return these names.

Comment: The revised code at the top of this post uses 'KnownValue : that's an error: it should be using 'KnownColor.

Answer (score 13):

This method uses reflection to examine the predefined colors on the `Color` class and compare them against the color passed in as an argument.  This can be optimized further, but it should give you an idea of the general technique.

```
private static String GetColorName(Color color)
{
    var predefined = typeof(Color).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    var match = (from p in predefined where ((Color)p.GetValue(null, null)).ToArgb() == color.ToArgb() select (Color)p.GetValue(null, null));
    if (match.Any())
       return match.First().Name;
    return String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `Any` then `First`, call `FirstOrDefault` then check if the result is null.

Comment: Color is a structure.  FirstOrDefault will return an empty color, not null.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the Color class from System.Drawing namespace, it has a static method FromARGB that returns a Color object.  It has several overloads, one allowing you to enter the RGB values like so:

```
var color = Color.FromArgb(100, 5,5,5).Name;
```

Comment: From the documentation: `This method returns either the user-defined name of the color, if the color was created from a name, or the name of the known color. For custom colors, the RGB value is returned.`

Comment: That **does not** return the name in the form "Red". For your example, the name comes out as 64050505.

Comment: Yes you guys are correct.  From MSDN:

"This method returns either the user-defined name of the color, if the color was created from a name, or the name of the known color. For custom colors, the RGB value is returned."

Answer (score 1):

For something quick and simple, try this (in WPF):

```
public string GetNameOfColor(Color color) {
    var colorProperty = typeof(Colors).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p =>
        (Color)(p.GetValue(p, null)) == color);
    return (colorProperty != null) ? colorProperty.Name : color.ToString();
}
```

In Visual Studio 2010, the `p.GetValue(p, null)` is required. In Visual Studio 2013+ you can just use `p.GetValue(p)`.

The advantage of this technique, besides its brevity, is that it doesn't require references to `System.Drawing` or `System.Reflection` but allows the user to remain inside the `System.Windows` namespace, which is WPF. It does require a reference to `System.Windows.Media` which you should probably already have if you are working with Colors in WPF. If you are like me, you try not to add `System.Drawing` to your WPF applications without a good need. As to why stay inside the WPF namespace, its a matter of preference. See for instance discussions at [WPF v/s System.Drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427848/wpf-v-s-system-drawing).

Comment: How is this different to the other two answers, and which part of it is WPF?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using .NETCF 3.5, and "System.Drawing.KnowColor enumeration" not exists.
For debug only, I'm using this function to return an known color;

```
public static string ColorName(System.Drawing.Color c)
{
    var colorName = string.Format("0x{0:X4}", c.ToArgb());
    var colorList = new List<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo>();
    var props = typeof(System.Drawing.Color).GetProperties();
    colorList.AddRange(props);
    props = typeof(System.Drawing.SystemColors).GetProperties();
    var prop = colorList.Where(p1 => (System.Drawing.Color)p1.GetValue(null, null) == c).FirstOrDefault();
    if (prop != null) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(prop.Name);
    else System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("unkown name Color");
    foreach (var item in colorList)
    {
        var argb = (System.Drawing.Color)item.GetValue(null, null);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("ColorName {0} ARGB {1:X4}", item.Name, argb.ToArgb()));
        if (c == argb) return item.Name;
    }

    return colorName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I recently was working on solving this same problem, I went and wrote a static lookup cache which can be pre-populated with well-known .NET Framework color values derived from the system enum `System.Drawing.KnownColor` indirectly. I decompiled .NET, and saw that the color properties call the constructor with the associated enum states. I am using reflection, but it's a one-time deal, that takes place in the static initializer of my class. This is NOT a thread-safe solution, but it can can be trivially made to be thread-safe, and also maintains a permanent cache in memory.

What can be useful about my approach, is while it first pre-populates with the list of .NET Named colors, you can also add application runtime-defined well-known colors - read from JSON, downloaded from the web, parsed from a database, etc... The major potential downside here, is that this is a singleton, due to being static, and there may be unwanted side-effects as a result of this design choice. Make this class instanced where you see fit.

I made the public-facing interface as simple as possible - `LookupName(Color)` returns `string.Empty` if there is a cache miss, or else, returns the string name of the color. `AddToCache(Color, string)` returns true on success, false on fail (say, a known value is already there). `ToNearestNamedColor(Color)` is a moderately expensive numerical method, derived from color quantization techniques, using the Pythagorean Distance to select the closest "named" color in the static cache, and it returns the string of the color name, the `System.Drawing.Color` structure for that name, and as a final bonus, a `double` representing the score, or fitness, of the nearest known / named `Color` input.

Using the Pythagorean Distance to select the closest named color is suboptimal, but provides a decent starting point, before using a different baseline heuristic to maximize approximate similarity.

Finally, `ToRGB(Color)` is a helper-function I wrote to convert a `System.Drawing.Color` to an integer representing the RGB values of the color, trimming (zeroing) the leading Alpha-component, stuffing a 24 bitstring into a 32-bit int structure.

`ToRGB(Color)` Helper (static extension) function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts the specified <see cref="Color"/> to a 24-bitstring on an int, of 00000000RRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBB.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="toRGB">The color to convert to rgb as a 24 bitstring. Ignores Alpha.</param>
/// <returns>an integer representation of the specified <see cref="Color"/>.</returns>
public static int ToRGB(this Color toRGB)
{
  return
    (toRGB.R << 16) |
    (toRGB.G << 8) |
    toRGB.B;
}
```

With this helper-function defined (could be public, could be internal, up to you), I now present my NamedColorStaticCache.cs (place in whatever namespace you want / need).

```
  // Using-statements:
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Reflection;

  /// <summary>
  /// Static class to assist with looking up known, named colors, by name.
  /// </summary>
  public static class NamedColorStaticCache
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Stores the lookup cache of RGB colors to known names.
    /// </summary>
    private static Dictionary<int, string> rgbLookupCache;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes static members of the <see cref="NamedColorStaticCache"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    static NamedColorStaticCache()
    {
      rgbLookupCache = new Dictionary<int, string>();
      Type colorType = typeof(Color);
      PropertyInfo[] knownColorProperties = colorType
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Where(t => t.PropertyType == typeof(Color))
        .ToArray();

      // Avoid treating "transparent" as "white".
      AddToCache(Color.White, "White");

      foreach (PropertyInfo pi in knownColorProperties)
      {
        Color asColor = (Color)pi.GetValue(null);
        AddToCache(asColor, pi.Name);
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Looks up the name of the specified <see cref="Color"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="toLookup">The <see cref="Color"/> to lookup a name for.</param>
    /// <returns>A string of the associated name of the specified <see cref="Color"/>.</returns>
    public static string LookupName(this Color toLookup)
    {
      int rgb = toLookup.ToRGB();
      if (rgbLookupCache.ContainsKey(rgb))
      {
        return rgbLookupCache[rgb];
      }

      return string.Empty;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified <see cref="Color"/> to a lookup cache of named colors.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="toAdd">The <see cref="Color"/> to add to the lookup cache.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the <see cref="Color"/> to add to the lookup cache.</param>
    /// <returns>True if adding successful, else, false (the color was already in the cache).</returns>
    public static bool AddToCache(this Color toAdd, string name)
    {
      int rgb = toAdd.ToRGB();
      if (rgbLookupCache.ContainsKey(rgb))
      {
        return false;
      }

      rgbLookupCache.Add(rgb, name);
      return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Takes the specified input <see cref="Color"/>, and translates it to its nearest counterpart, using root square sum.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="toNearest">The <see cref="Color"/> to look up to the nearest named color.</param>
    /// <returns>A tuple structure of name, color, error.</returns>
    public static Tuple<string, Color, double> ToNearestNamedColor(this Color toNearest)
    {
      string foundName = string.Empty;
      Color foundColor = Color.Black;
      double error = double.MaxValue;

      int toNearestRGB = toNearest.ToRGB();
      if (rgbLookupCache.ContainsKey(toNearestRGB))
      {
        foundName = rgbLookupCache[toNearestRGB];
        foundColor = toNearest;
        error = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in rgbLookupCache)
        {
          int rgb = pair.Key;
          byte r = (byte)(rgb >> 16);
          byte g = (byte)(rgb << 16 >> 24);
          byte b = (byte)(rgb << 24 >> 24);
          int dr = r - toNearest.R;
          int dg = g - toNearest.G;
          int db = b - toNearest.B;
          double newError =
            Math.Sqrt(
              (dr * dr) +
              (dg * dg) +
              (db * db));

          if (newError < error)
          {
            foundName = pair.Value;
            foundColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
            error = newError;
          }

          if (newError <= .0005)
          {
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      return Tuple.Create(foundName, foundColor, error);
    }
  }
```

Note: Edited an hour later to provide the lookup function to grab the nearest named color. This is not the *best* way to do it (converting to `CIEL*a*b*` would be "better"), but this is a solid foundation using a ToNearestColor-approach. This way the original poster can give the closest approximate color name, in addition to looking up solely discrete color names.