# Get the BackColor of all cells in dataGridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, streamwriter

I want to get the BackColor of all the cells and write them into a text file, so the output would be:
**YellowGreen**
**Orange**
**SteelBlue**, etc.

This is what I've tried:

```
 void GetColors()
    {
        string path = Application.StartupPath + @"/test.txt";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
        int n = 0;
        DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView1.Columns[n++];
        DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

        sw.WriteLine(cell.Style.BackColor);
        column.CellTemplate = cell;

        sw.Close();
    }
```

I tried `cell.Style.BackColor.ToString();` and `.ToArgb();`
With ToString(); I get `Color {Empty}` in output and with ToArgb I get `0`.

Can someone help me please? Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Apparently, it's just not set. What do you need it for?

Comment: I want to replace an XML save source instead of a text file, beacause I'm getting many problems using the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't referencing the existing cells when you make a *new* DataGridViewTextBoxCell object.

Try enumerating through the existing cells:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
  foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) {
    sw.WriteLine(cell.Style.BackColor.ToKnownColor().ToString());
  }
}
```

To save and read the color scheme of your grid, you can save the row and column information into your string:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
  foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) {
    sw.WriteLine(string.Join(";", cell.RowIndex.ToString(),
                                  cell.ColumnIndex.ToString(),
                                  GetColorName(cell.Style.BackColor)));
  }
}
```

The GetColorName function comes from [How to get the name of color while having its RGB value in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11728366/719186)

To update the grid with the colors from the file, you would parse the information:

```
foreach (string s in File.ReadAllLines(@"yourfile")) {
  string[] items = s.Split(';');
  if (items.Length == 3) {
    dgv.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(items[0])]
       .Cells[Convert.ToInt32(items[1])]
       .Style.BackColor = Color.FromName(Convert.ToString(items[2]));
  }
}
```

Omitted any error checking for brevity.  Obviously, the number of rows and columns in the file would have to match what the datagridview control is displaying.

Comment: Still getting `0` in the output, and all my cells are set to Red Color

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss How did you set the backcolors of the grid cells? If you set them with `.BackColor = Color.Red;` then this code will work.

Comment: I set the backolors in the DefaultCellStyle option in the designer properties. Sorry about that, now I know why it wasn't working.

Comment: But, can I read the text file in same way, you were writing it?

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss See [How to get the name of color while having its RGB value in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11728412/719186) on converting a RGB color to a KnownColor.  It requires Reflection.

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss You were just writing the colors to a line in a file, so you weren't saving the row or column information for each color.  That requires you to save that information, too, and then parse it when you read the file.

Comment: So how can I make that?

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss It can be as simple as `row#;column#;color` and when you read the file, you would split the string on the semi-colon, then you have an array where the first item is the row, second item is the column, etc.  If you need help, try working it out, and if you get stuck, click on the Ask Question link on top since that would be a different question than the one you asked here.

Comment: Could you help me to make it work? 'Cause I am trying this since 2 days, and the only functional but problematic way I found was XML. And I've tried making loops and all that stuff, but I can't make it work. You could help me in the chat discussion. Can you help me?

Comment: GetColorName should be a class right?(from the link you wrote)

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss Could be if you wanted to.  It's just a static function so it can be placed anywhere really.