# Converting long value representing color to ARGB color code in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a long number from a csv file (which defines color) to ARGB color  code. using the following code (which I got from stackoverflow),

```
var argbVal = Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)this.dgvDisplayFlags.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value )["Color"]);

dgvDisplayFlags.Rows[i].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(argbVal);
```

However it is not working. showing an exception "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'".

Can any one help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: As the error says you're trying to cast a string to `DataRowView`. The `Value` you get is not a `DataRowView` so don't cast it as such.

Comment: `this.dgvDisplayFlags.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value` is the string value of the cell, it can't be converted to `DataRowView`. remove the casting.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you have any idea on converting  a long value to ARGB color code?

Answer (score 0):

do not cast to DataRowView

```
var argbVal = Convert.ToInt32(this.dgvDisplayFlags.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728209/how-to-get-the-name-of-color-while-having-its-rgb-value-in-c) for answer how to get color name from ARGB